# Next13 - Change parent client component state in child client component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As the client component can only have serializable props in Next13, we can't pass functions to the props of a child that is also a client component.

In my use case, I have a state that is managed by the parent and I want to change displayed data according to the value of that state variable. My issue is comming when I want to change the state because we already have a `<Select />` component that takes an `onChange` method and I want to pass the `setState` method to the `onChange`.

Is this is possible with Next 13, because I don't found any alternative solution, except perhaps to store the state in a global context ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a slight miss-conception about the rules regarding the serialization of components. Only props passed from the Server to Client Components need to be [serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Serialization). This means that values such as functions, Dates, etc, cannot be passed directly to Client Components from Server Components.

But when dealing with two client components, you can use the following approach based on the above question:

```
const ChildComponent = ({ onChange }) => {
  return <input onChange={onChange} />;
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [event, setEvent] = useState(null);
  const onChange = (e) => setEvent(e);
  return <ChildComponent onChange={onChange} />;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so it's a misunderstanding on my part !
I'm struggling a bit with the new concepts introduce by React 18 and the logic behind server and client components.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Pleosy No worries, Next.js 13 can be a real dragon to deal with. I strongly recommend you check out the official documentation on the updated [react essentials](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials), specifically the part about [component serialization](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#passing-props-from-server-to-client-components-serialization).